# My text is skewed

Tags: horizontal-alignment, overleaf, text

it is a bit strange. I changed the default font and width in Latex, and now my text is skewed, please look at this template (this isn't my original text, but this template has the same issue). Please have a look at this template (especially page 2, the text is not straight, I find it a bit difficult to explain what I mean, but I hope you can see/understand what I mean):

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/proceedings-of-the-linguistic-society-of-america-template-v-2-dot-3/dbyndfxkwqrs.pdf

This is the code of the template:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}   
\UseRawInputEncoding
% PERSONAL PACKAGES [add below] 
\usepackage{expex,marvosym,tabularray,xcolor}

%%% LSA LAYOUT AND PACKAGES
\usepackage{times} %obsolete, but works for the font and style
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{natbib}
    \setcitestyle{semicolon,aysep={},yysep={,},notesep={:}}
    %see below for instructions on natbib bibliography

\usepackage{lipsum} % this and the following package and the settings beneath them are for maintaining indentation and still having ragged-right alignmnent
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength\RaggedRightParindent{0.3in}
\RaggedRight

\usepackage{scrextend} % this package and the following settings are for the footnote formatting
\deffootnote[.5em]{0em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}

\newcounter{savefootnote}   % these settings allow the use of an asterisk as a footnote label (for the author line below the title.
\newcounter{symfootnote}
\newcommand{\symfootnote}[1]{%
   \setcounter{savefootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{symfootnote}}%
   \ifnum\value{footnote}>8\setcounter{footnote}{0}\fi%
   \let\oldthefootnote=\thefootnote%
   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
   \footnote{#1}%
   \let\thefootnote=\oldthefootnote%
   \setcounter{symfootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{savefootnote}}%
}

\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{.5em}{}[.]
    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\scshape}{\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}[.]
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\scshape}{\thesubsubsection.}{.5em}{}[.]
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}    
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors={black},urlcolor={blue}]{hyperref}
```

[image]

Comment: don't use external links, also unrelated but `\UseRawInputEncoding` breaks almost all latex character handling it has uses for some specific legacy compatablity issues but are you _sure_ you want it here (especally on overleaf it can only do harm as the file is always utf-8)

Comment: you have not posted an example that  produces any text so we can not debug your margins.

Comment: I see nothing wrong on page 2?

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle I don't know how to describe it, maybe my eyes are just fucking me up :) but it seems like the text is not straight, I mean..... yeah i really don't know which word I should use, but the paragraphs are just not straight. The code is actually the code of the latex template, my own file has a different code , but the same issue (and my own code is based on this template. Thanks for the tip (about RawInputEncoding!).

Comment: I added an image of page 2, with a vertical rule showing left margin, what part do you find strange? you could edit the image in an image editor and add arrows pointing out unexpected spaces